# CSS class selector not working inside of ID element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to change the link with anchor text 'Prev' green, but when I use the ID attribute, the link stays blue

```
#page a {color: blue;}
a {color: green;}
```

I realize I can do the following, but let's say I can't prepend with #page since I won't know the ID name:

```
#page a.prev { color: green; }
```

I have tried the follow to no avail:

```
.nav-links > a { color: green; }
```

or

```
.nav-links > a.prev { color: green; }
```

The CSS prev link is always overridden to blue. How can I change to green?

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
  <nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
    <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Posts navigation</h2>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <a class="prev page-numbers" href="#">Prev</a>
      <a class='page-numbers' href='#'>1</a>
      <span aria-current='page' class='page-numbers current'>2</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: it's all about specificty, you need to understand this and you will get it

Comment: target the class